# Multiple figures with sub

Tags: subfloats

I'm trying to insert multiple figures under 1 caption. I use subfloat and don't know how to fit all my figures in 1 page of document. Can someone help me? Thank you in advance!

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{fig1}} & 
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{fig2}} & \\
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{fig3}} & 
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{fig4}}\\
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{fig5}}\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{correlation}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please, consider this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381473/only-one-caption-under-multiple-subfigures

Comment: how big are your images?

Comment: ... it depends on the size. But you could try [How to create subfloat figures (two in first row and one below)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64859/124842) ...with two in first row, two in second row and one below? You could use `width=0.45\textwidth`,...

Comment: It's ok now. Sorry because of this dumb question. I'm a very beginner in LaTeX

Comment: Why are you using `\subfloat` to begin with? It's only useful if each image has a subcaption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{fig1}}
    \hfill
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{fig2}}

\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{fig3}}
    \hfill
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{fig4}}\

\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{fig5}}\\
    \caption{correlation}
    \label{fig:corr}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**
similar result you can obtain, as pointed [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) in his comment below, also without use of `\subfloat` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{fig1}
    \hfill
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{fig2}

\medskip
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{fig3}
    \hfill
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{fig4}

\medskip
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{fig5}
    \caption{correlation}
    \label{fig:corr}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's no need for `\subfloat` if no subcaption is required.

Comment: @egreg, you have right. but then you need to add vertical space between rows with images. i add this possibility to my answer. thank you for pointing this!