# put (a) and (b) to one in subfigures

Tags: subfloats

I want to delete (a) and (b) from the subfigure and put the only one (a) in the middle of the subfigure like this.
could anyone help me? thank you

I want something like this: [image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381473/only-one-caption-under-multiple-subfigures

Comment: have alook at the answer below

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: well, so they're not really subfigures, no? It's just one figure... with an `(a)` in the middle of two graphic elements. Or did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 4):

As I commented, it seems to me that you really want just one figure --- not two subfigures. If this is the case, you can simply use this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \quad
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}

    (a)
    \caption{Whatever}
    \label{fig:name}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % omit 'demo' option for real document
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=4cm]{c1.eps}
            \qquad  % choose separation between c1 and c2
            \includegraphics[width=4cm]{c2.eps}
            \caption{V} \label{fig:a}
        \end{subfigure}
        
%       \caption{(a) and (b) represent circles} \label{fig:wind_speed}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```